# MySQL, huge size table and I don't know what is using the space

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have this WordPress table which has 26GB size:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "my_database"
    AND table_name = "wpii_options";
```

Result:

```
{
  "TABLE_CATALOG": "def",
  "TABLE_SCHEMA": "my_database",
  "TABLE_NAME": "wpii_options",
  "TABLE_TYPE": "BASE TABLE",
  "ENGINE": "InnoDB",
  "VERSION": 10,
  "ROW_FORMAT": "Compact",
  "TABLE_ROWS": 13793552,
  "AVG_ROW_LENGTH": 2025,
  "DATA_LENGTH": 27932049408,
  "MAX_DATA_LENGTH": 0,
  "INDEX_LENGTH": 98304,
  "DATA_FREE": 7340032,
  "AUTO_INCREMENT": 16465,
  "CREATE_TIME": "2016-07-26 04:28:08",
  "UPDATE_TIME": null,
  "CHECK_TIME": null,
  "TABLE_COLLATION": "utf8_general_ci",
  "CHECKSUM": null,
  "CREATE_OPTIONS": "",
  "TABLE_COMMENT": ""
}
```

For starting the "TABLE_ROWS" field fluctuates between 10Million and 40Million every time I run the above query, but in reallity the number of rows is not that much:

```
select count(*) from wpii_options;
```

Result:

```
292
```

But the most important part is that I don't know where all the 26GB are used:

```
show create table wpii_options;
```

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE `wpii_options` (
  `option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `option_name` varchar(191) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `option_value` longtext NOT NULL,
  `autoload` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16465 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Checking the size of each column:

```
select 
  sum(length(option_id)) as option_id_length,
  sum(length(option_name)) as option_name_length,
  sum(length(option_value)) as option_value_length,
  sum(length(autoload)) as autoload_length
from wpii_options;
```

Result:

```
{
  "option_id_length": 816,
  "option_name_length": 6533,
  "option_value_length": 523982,
  "autoload_length": 836
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Where are the 26GB that this table is using?
2. Why the Number of Rows in the table status are millions but if I count them explicitly there are only a few (262)?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue:

```
optimize table wpii_options;
```